# ActiveAdmin's export to .csv is missing object attributes (Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, csv, export, activeadmin

I am using Active Admin 0.6.3 in my Rails 3.2 app. When I use the link in the bottom-left corner of an index to export to .csv I am noticing that several of the object's attributes are being left out, including some crucial ones.

For example, I am trying to export the Jobs table. Every job has a `user_id` attribute that shows which user is associated with the job. However, this row is not appearing in the .csv file generated by the export action.

When I export to JSON, all of the object's database attributes are present. However, none of the custom columns that I created in the ActiveAdmin index are included in the export. This is a separate but related problem.

Can anyone help me understand why this is taking and find a solution so that all of the database attribtues for my objects shows up in the .csv? And is not possible to have AA export what's actually in my AA index (including custom columns) and not just the values pulled directly from the object in the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, AA provides instruction in its docs about how to customize the .csv export format. The process is very similar to customizing the index view itself:

http://activeadmin.info/docs/4-csv-format.html